# Django: Page not found but path is shown

Tags: python, html, django, url

I have recently started using Django and I am a little lost as to why my services.html page does not render as I have followed what appears to be the same steps I took for my home page to work but I keep getting the error that nothing matches the current path. Below are my snippets for views and urls.py. I also had it be included in my website urls.py by using  `path('', include('affiliate.urls')),`

```
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
[name='services']
The current path, services.html, didn't match any of these.
```

```
Urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [         
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('', views.services, name="services"),

]
```

```
Views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def services(request):
    return render(request, 'services.html', {})
```

Comment: Both have the same `path`, so that means the first one that matches will always fire, hence the `home` view. You should give another path to the `seervices`, for example `'services/'`, then you can visit that with `/services`. Note that the name of the *template* is nto relevant for the URL, this is just a mechanism to render a response.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more so are you saying I should change  `path('', views.services, name="services"),`  to  `path('services', views.services, name="services"),`

Comment: no `services/` for example, and visit it with `localhost:8000/services/` for example.

Comment: I have made this change and it works but I would like to have a nav link to go to this location as well I am assuming `<a class="nav-link" href="/services">` would work?

Comment: please make use of the `{% url ... %}` template tag to resolve links: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the link so I can read up on this! Learned even more about using Django!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your urlpatterns as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [         
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('services/', views.services, name="services"),

]
```

Now when you want to access the services view, make sure to use 127.0.0.1:8000/services
because both of your paths for home and services are pointing to the same url.

Willem is trying to explain you the same thing.

Comment: I currently have `<a class="nav-link" href="services.html">` as my link what would it have to be to travel to that page?

Comment: Ohh man
Play with url
I often use jinja format to provide url
Inside your href, provide the url that points to your name in the urlpatterns

Try this:
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'services' %}">